# How can I list all the wifi sources in range with their signal strength?

Tags: wireless, 15.10

How can I list all the wifi sources in range with their signal strength in Ubuntu 15.10, even without knowing passwords of wifi ? Can I do this? 
Basically I want to map my workplace based on strength of different wifi signals to get the location based on wifi strength.

Since my ubuntu 15.10 shows me list of all available wifi sources to connect to with their signal strengths in a graphic form where I can use one of them and enter password to get connected, I want to know is their a way to get list of wifi source names, their signal strength in numeric terms through a bash command or something?

Comment: Your question isn't clear update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `nmcli` to find what you're looking for:

```
[itnet7@localhost ~]$ nmcli device wifi list
*  SSID           MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
   --             Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  90      ▂▄▆█  WPA2      
*  Xunil_51       Infra  149   54 Mbit/s  66      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
   HoltzGuest     Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WEP       
   ThatGuy        Infra  1     54 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
   CAT-HOME       Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
   tla11854       Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  29      ▂___  WPA2
```

You can even use `nmcli` to connect to one

```
nmcli device wifi connect HoltzGuest password <enter password here>
```

If you're in a graphical environment and attempt to connect to an SSID that requires a key or password without specifying anything, you will get prompted like so:

[image: Screenshot of Graphical Authentication connect to wifi via nmcli]

Comment: Answer better than my own (no need for sudo). However my nmcli (0.9.8.8) has a slightly different output.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

(of course, you replace wlan0 by the name of your active wifi interface)

Comment: Using nmcli (see itnet7's answer) is likely a better solution (no need for sudo).

Answer (score 1):

You can use kismet . With kismet (expect with the indications about the signal strength and other basic inforamtion )you can have a gps adapter and map your entire area for wifi access points . The gps coordinates are taken by kismet and can also be displayed with google earth .

Feel free to visit the tools' webpage : http://www.kismetwireless.net/

Also there are plenty of tutorials on youtube and the internet in general !